# How to combat aliens taking away the feelings of eros/lust? Which will lead to human extinction

Tags: biology, science-fiction, aliens

As the title says, these aliens has silently been sucking out the feelings of eros/lust. which will make humankind extinct in a few hundreds of years.

These aliens are unquestionably very advanced, in fact, they can wipe out human life within an hour if so they wanted with both biological and technological weapons. They can even modify memories through light. But the aliens abhor violence, so they decided instead that they will let us go extinct. Not by war but by taking away the drive force of committing sexual acts or lust that will inevitably lead to reproduction. If there's no reproduction, then no human beings will be born.

These aliens can manipulate feelings to a very fine degree. But they can't control the human mind.

We don't know that these aliens exist. And they are, however, willing to accelerate our extinction through natural or biological means, but nothing to invasive like viruses or alien bacteria.

Practically they can incite wrath among the top echelons of the government and start a world war which will inevitably lead humans to develop technologies that will probably defeat the aliens or it will turn into a nuclear war which will turn the world uninhabitable that it will need a few hundreds of years and a lot of resources to re-terraform. So this is the best option possible to them.

If these can be fought by us, then the aliens will be willing to be brought to the negotiating table

Comment: Eventually governments will just be paying people to reproduce so this won't really work.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. but then again they can turn that feeling of lust into something fear or gross or even abhorring ... these aliens can manipulate feelings.. but not mind. Their aim is to make us not reproduce that will lead to an over all extinction of human kind

Comment: I believe the desire to have kids is not exactly the same as lust. Not all children are accidents made out of sexual desire, and mothers can still be inseminated artificially ; this tactic will just slow down birthrate mostly in poor countries, and prevent unwanted children worldwide. I do not think this is a good plot element, as your aliens seem to lack imagination.  There is a virtually infinite number of ways to exterminate a race without violence.

Comment: @mico villena Humans can usually work past their primal urges for the betterment of society. But since you are making your aliens basically Godlike in power level compared to humans, they can do what ever they want. People also don't need to have sex to reproduce anyways, artificial insemination is perfectly valid way to produce humans.

Comment: @Spectantibus then how will this plot work? its just that this idea of mine is so surreal that i want it to be the center of the plot. The aliens doesnt like violence so instead they manipulate us to not reproduce as in turning baby making into something abhorring, something that we all dislike something that women will fear(say 90% mortality rate per pregnancy) i want this to be the center of that plot. how will i make it work?

Comment: @A.C.A.C. how can i make this plot work then?

Comment: Wow, wow, now you are asking a completely different question - "How aliens can manipulate humanity so it will go extinct?"

Comment: @Alexander my imagination does run rampant every day. One way for me to not go crazy is to write it down.

Comment: If the aliens are as advanced as you say, they can just engineer a virus that produces a contraceptive and infect the whole world.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. thats the thing these aliens doesnt want to do that, they just want us to die/extinct naturally as possible So that they may preserve what is probably left of us once they take over earth

Comment: @mico villena - then it might be better for you to ask a new question. Comment section here is poorly suited for a discussion.

Comment: @Alexander i am adding details on this question on the fly to fill the gap on the logic holes that other people see than me. I think asking this question is doing just that. I cant really talk with anyone willing to answer my questions most of the time

Comment: @mico villena - I think you received an answer to question that it currently in the title (I you may get more answers to the original question). "How will i make it work?" is a different question.

Comment: @Alexander i shall ask that but not now. I will let other people answer this question first then i'll ask that question after 2-3 days

Comment: How is a forced contraceptive (say, a virus that destroys every human egg cell on the planet) less natural than a magical raygun that removes several of the most basic desires our species has? Also, I feel like you're basically asking "how can humanity defeat undefeatable aliens?", which obviously has no answer. Finally, how can they modify emotions and memories but "can't control the human mind"?

Comment: Based on my casual observation of random parents, either lust is not necessary for reproduction, or a good many people have radically different tastes than I do.

Answer (score 3):

#### Research

First, you're going to have to research how this emotional control works. Is it a beam that can be blocked or reversed? Is this something that can be overridden via pills, like a the various erectile dysfunction pills today? Are some people immune to the effects? If so, how? (and so on) They will need more data on the how before they can form a plan to block...

#### Propaganda

While research spools up, propaganda campaigns will be needed to encourage people to "Have one for the team" or "Keep Calm and Procreate On" or whatever. These ad campaigns probably will have, at best, minimal effort. But governments will try them anyway.

#### Power through

Some folks will take or be encouraged to take medicines to artificially induce physical arousal. It may result in pregnancies, even if neither participant is emotionally aroused. Some people do this already to get children (those with low libido, or who just aren't into sex). Scale that up.

#### Airborne sprays, something in the water, etc.

If a chemical additive can temporarily block the alien power, then that'll be used. Infuse it into the water supply, start mass inoculations, or spray it from crop dusters... whatever works, we'll take it.

#### Artificial insemination

For families that want children, artificial insemination may be the best way forward. No sex, but you still get children.

## Doomed to Fail.

All of the above is doomed to fail. Once the aliens spot a group trying to "test-market" a possible solution, they can simply go in and wipe the memories of all involved. With the ability to modify both emotions and memories, anyone who attempts to publicly and actively solve this problem will suddenly get reset to less than zero. They will forget their potential solutions. They will be too angry or depressed to try to re-discover their solutions.

And any group that can organize around protecting the researchers and developers will find themselves too angry/depressed/etc. to remain impartial. Each such group will devolve into chaos, split apart, and then forget what they knew about solving the problem.

*In the end, no group can win against these aliens.* Only through complete secrecy is there any hope. But with secrecy, you lose the ability to scale up your solutions to a global scale. Pockets of people, if they can hide, might succeed. But at the global level, society will collapse under these mind-control aliens.

Answer (score 1):

No, humanity will not go extinct.

As stated in the question, "alien ray" would block erotic feeling, but not the desire to procreate. And it's the latter, not former, that is responsible for most babies around, even in developing countries.

Also, "alien ray" (as currently stated) would not make opposite sexes revolting to each other - only the carnal part of the interaction would be affected. Which means that dating and falling in love would still going on as before. People would still be getting married, even if it would be a sexless marriage.

After that, they could either overcome their revulsion, or move to artificial insemination (which would not require any high tech).

So, the humanity would survive. The human culture, however, would change a lot.

Comment: Lets say the act of reproduction becomes repulsive together with abhorring the feeling of lust to multiply the effect?

Comment: Then my answer would stay. "Platonic feelings" are not going anywhere.

Comment: lets say lets take lust to the extreme of love then turn it into hate. not in hate of procreating but hate of child instead of love. Produce normal cases of infanticide to parents say 3 out of 10 for the next few generations of infanticide then 9 out 10 cases of mild to  extreme child abuse. would that lead to the desired outcome?

Comment: no feelings of lust amplified by mild to extreme cases of child abuse + 3 out of 10 ratings of infanticide will in what i think achieve the result of extinction

Comment: "Hate of children" would work much better for your scenario. You don't even need much of infanticide - people would generally stop having children in the first place.

Comment: and taking away lust will amplify the effect of that hate of children

Answer (score -1):

Well, having been around ace and aromantic people for some time while I worked as counselor in a LGBTQ center I meet many people that didn't wanted sex, but wanted to have sons and daughters someday.

Since these aliens are godlike, then there is no way to really fight them, but if that's their only attack then humanity should just wait the aliens get bored and move on.

Comment: They are in it for millions of years if necessary. These alien race like to collect races as if a collection. SO that others wont take their collection they will pursue the extinction of the collection so that the few that they have will be the most priced ones of that collection. But as i said their method is assured extinction multiple hundreds of years we will be extinct still regardless

Comment: So they will need to do more than just eliminate lust, if they are going to wait millions of years if necessary than there is no way to fight them.

Comment: lust is just an amplfier or just another form of an emotion... if they make procreating artificial or natural otherwise be abhorring or outright wrath inciting which later produces child abuses to extreme and will be normal cases of infanticide.